# Shell Script to Start and Stop an Executable JAR in Linux Environment

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, jar

I have to write a start and stop script for an executable jar (e.g., executable.jar).

How to do it using shell scripting?

I got success to do it for Windows environment with *.bat* file. But not able to manage to write a shell script for same.

Comment: What distro? You're probably better off writing an init, upstart or systemd script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simple version:
you can write a little script as the one below (save it as MyStart.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar executable.jar &      # You send it in background
MyPID=$!                        # You sign it's PID
echo $MyPID                     # You print to terminal
echo "kill $MyPID" > MyStop.sh  # Write the the command kill pid in MyStop.sh
```

When you execute this script with `/bin/bash MyStart.sh`, it will print the PID of that process on the screen.

Else you can change the attribute to MyStart.sh (`chmod u+x MyStart.sh`) and run it simply with `./MyStart.sh`.

To stop the process you can write by command line `kill 1234` where 1234 is the PID answered by the script, or `/bin/bash MyStop.sh`

Remember to delete the script MyStop.sh after that you use it.

Comment: Thanks Hastur. Your logic worked for my problem. This is what I am expecting.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run a separate script to stop the task.

Borrowing from Hastur's script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar executable.jar &      # Send it to the background
MyPID=$!                        # Record PID
echo $MyPID                     # Print to terminal
# Do stuff
kill $MyPID                     # kill PID (can happen later in script as well)
```